# Override std::equal

Tags: c++, templates, unordered-map

In providing a specialization for the equal_to operator for std::unordered_map, I was wondering if it's possible to determine which of the lhs or rhs is the data currently stored in the hashmap? I'd like to do something like this:

```
template<>
struct equal_to<METADATA>
{
    bool operator() (METADATA const& data1, METADATA const& data2)
    {
        if (data1.Size == data2.Size)
        {
            // Need to look up the stored pointer in a global data structure
            SIZE_T Pointer = g_Pointer + data1.Offset;

            return memcmp(reinterpret_cast<void*>(Pointer), reinterpret_cast<void*>(data2.Pointer), data1.Size) == 0;
        }

        return false;            
    }
};
```

Thanks.

Comment: What hashmap are you referring to?

Comment: Updated with std::unordered_map

Comment: Equality is supposed to be symmetric. Please don't do this.

Comment: @FredOverflow: Of course it's symmetric, but what if one of the two sides is more symmetric than the other? :-)

Comment: How can you assign to `data1.Pointer` if `data1` is `const METADATA& data1`? is it `mutable`?

Comment: My bad. It doesn't have to be data1.Pointer. It just have to be a temporary variable for the comparison. Updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have the temporary `METADATA` contain a flag that determines whether you will use the global pointer or not. Probably use a sentinel value for `Offset` or `Pointer`.

```
template<>
struct equal_to<METADATA>
{
    bool operator() (METADATA const& data1, METADATA const& data2)
    {
        if (data1.Size == data2.Size)
        {
            // Need to look up the stored pointer in a global data structure
            void * pointer1 = data1.Pointer;
            if (pointer1 == NULL)
                pointer1 = g_Pointer + data1.Offset;
            void * pointer2 = data2.Pointer;
            if (pointer2 == NULL)
                pointer2 = g_Pointer + data2.Offset;

            return memcmp(pointer1, pointer2, data1.Size) == 0;
        }

        return false;            
    }
};
```